# How to get the name of the query just ran on AfterRefresh procedure?

Tags: vba

When I push the button "Refresh all" I would like to know what is the name of the query on the AfterRefresh procedure?

```vb
Sub QueryTable_AfterRefresh(Success As Boolean)
    If Success Then
        Debug.Print "Success" 'here I want to know the name of the query just ran
    Else
        Debug.Print "Failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried this but I got an error

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyQuery As QueryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If Success Then
        MsgBox "Query hass been refresed " & MyQuery.Name
    Else
        MsgBox "Query failed"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyQuery_BeforeRefresh(Cancel As Boolean)
'    If MsgBox("Refresh query? ", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

I have a class module: clsQuery

```vb
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyQuery As QueryTable

Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
If Success Then
    MsgBox "Query hass been refresed "
Else
    MsgBox "Query failed"
End If

End Sub
```

and in a regular module (Module1) I have:

```vb
Dim colQueries As New Collection

Sub InitializeQueries()

Dim clsQ As clsQuery
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim QT As QueryTable
Dim LO As ListObject

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each QT In WS.QueryTables
            Set clsQ = New clsQuery
            Set clsQ.MyQuery = QT
            colQueries.Add clsQ
        Next QT
        For Each LO In WS.ListObjects
            Set QT = LO.QueryTable
            Set clsQ = New clsQuery
            Set clsQ.MyQuery = QT
            colQueries.Add clsQ
        Next LO
    Next WS

End Sub
```

And on "ThisWorkBook" each time the workbook opens I call the procedure to initialize the queries:

```vb
Public Sub Workbook_open()

 Call InitializeQueries
End Sub
```

The "AfterRefresh" works, however, I want to know which query thrown the event in order to call the appropriate macro, because when I click on the ribbon "Refresh All" all the queries runs in background and some are more heavy than others and take different times to process. So, in the "If Success" of the AfterRefresh I want to identify which query thrown the event. is that possible?

Comment: Could help mentioning what error you got.

Comment: Maybe make sure you followed the steps outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-events-with-the-querytable-object

Comment: Please edit your question if you need to add details - too difficult to read in comments

Comment: What exact error did you get when you tried using `MsgBox "Query hass been refresed " & MyQuery.Name`  ?

Comment: Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub MyQuery_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    
    Dim msg As String

    msg = "Query '" & MyQuery.ListObject.Name & "' refresh " & _
          IIf(Success, " succeeded", " failed")
    
    'Some options....
    MsgBox msg

    Debug.Print msg

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Cells(rows.count,"A").End(xlUp). _
            Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(Now, msg)

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Tim, Thanks a lot for your help, Just one additional question: How I know how many queries are? (I don't see any "count" property...) I want realize if the query just ran is the last one.

Comment: You can swap out the MsgBox for (eg) a `Debug.Print`, or log the messages to a worksheet with a timestamp. See edits above.